# Unequal vertical margins between headings and paragraphs

Tags: html, css

I've hit a slightly strange snag with margins. I don't think I've noticed this before. I'm unable to get my margins between a heading and paragraph to be equal across all instances on the page. I've tried various things, like using spans instead of paragraphs just to test, playing with the margins, putting divs around each instance, but I still get this. I've even reduced styling to the absolute minimum to just test this, and I get the following: http://s17.postimg.org/4t2tpgnu7/margins.png

As you can see, there's a difference in margins between the paragraph text and the next heading, with the last being 16px and the other two 17px. There's also a difference between the margins between the actual headings and the paragraph text, with the first being 17px and the others being 16px. That screencap comes from the following code. As you can see, very simplified test code.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1 {

    font-family:'serif';
    font-size:21px;
    color:#4d4d4d;
}
h2 {    
    font-family:'serif';
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:italic;
    color:#4d4d4d;
}
p {
    font-family:'serif';
    font-size:12px;
    color:#4d4d4d;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page-content">
        <h2>ABOUT US</h2>
        <p>Lorem</p>
        <h2>WHO WE ARE</h2>
        <p>Lorem</p>
        <h2>WHY US</h2>
        <p>Lorem</p>
        <h2>CONTACT US</h2>
        <p>Lorem</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But yet I'm still getting unequal vertical margins between elements. Not sure I've noticed this before. I'd prefer the vertical margins between the text and the next heading to be the same. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Try defining the the margins in the css itself.

```
p {
font-family:'serif';
font-size:12px;
color:#4d4d4d;
margin-top: 17px; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have tried playing around with the margins in the CSS. I get that vertical margin discrepancy with or without margins.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/h7ah5ybh/

Ensure a particular margin is rendered by specifically declaring it:

```
margin: 17px 0;
```

Just apply it to `<h2>`s and `<p>`s.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried playing around with margins on both elements. I still get different margins in between elements. Actually, I even get a discrepancy in margins in your fiddle: http://s4.postimg.org/6qt2mhxyl/fiddle_margins.png